# match subjects separated by comma from two different table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

i have the requirement where need to match subjects known by student and posted_subjets by institute,and this subjects separated by comma
.i have written following code,its working fine but it looks quite long..
can anyone tell me the other way to do it.
   following is table structure

```
posted_subjets table                                                            student table
-----------------------------------------------------                           -----------------------------------    
posted_subjets_id  | degree  | subject_required |     institute_id               student_id  |  subjects
1                  |   MS   |  maths,electronics,CAD     2                         1           craft,drama 
2                    BSC       chemistry,biology         3                         2           maths
3                    arts      craft,drama,dancing        1                        3           cad,electronics
```

following is working code

```
public function match_subjects($sub,$sub_id)
        {
            $student_id=$this->session->userdata('student_id');
            $flag = False;

            $y=0;
            while($y<count($sub))
            {
                $sql="SELECT subjects 
                      FROM student
                      WHERE subjetcs
                      LIKE '%$sub[$y]%' 
                      AND student_id = '$student_id'";

                $query=$this->db->query($sql);

                if(count($query->result()))
                {   
                    $flag = TRUE;
                }
                $y++;
            }

            if($flag)
            {   
                $sql='SELECT subjets      
                      FROM posted_subjets
                      WHERE posted_subjets_id ='.$sub_id;

                $query=$this->db->query($sql);

                $b=array();

                foreach ($query->result() as $row)
                {
                    $subjets       = $row->subjets      ;

                }

                $subjets      =$this->multiexplode(array(',',' '),$subjets      );

                $flag=false;
                $x=0;

                for($i=0;$i<count($sub);$i++)
                {
                echo $sub;
                    for($k=0;$k<count($subjets );$k++)
                    {   
                        $subjets      [$k] = strtolower($subjets      [$k]);
                        $sub[$i] = strtolower($sub[$i]);
                        if($subjets      [$k]==$sub[$i])
                        {
                            $flag=true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if($flag)
                {
                    while($x<count($subjets))
                    {
                        $sql="SELECT subjects
                              FROM student
                              WHERE subjects LIKE '%$subjets[$x]%' 
                              AND student_id = '$student_id'";
                        $query=$this->db->query($sql);

                        if(count($query->result()))
                        {   
                            $reg_user_id=$this->session->userdata('student_id');

                            $query=$this->db->query("SELECT institute_id 
                                                     FROM posted_subjets
                                                     WHERE posted_subjets_id=".$sub_id
                                                     );

                            foreach($query->result() as $row)
                            {
                                $eid=$row->employer_id;
                            }
                            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO applied_subject(posted_subjets_id,institute_id,student_id,action)
                                              VALUES (".$job_id.",'$eid','$student_id','Applied')"
                                              );

                            $this->db->query("UPDATE posted_subjetcs 
                                              SET application_count=application_count+1 
                                              WHERE posted_subjets_id=".$sub_id
                                            );
                            return true;
                        }
                        $x++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

if anyone can tell me the other way to do it.

Comment: what you really want to do can you explain?

Comment: I feel that your database has a design flaw, making you code way more that you should have to. You should pull a new table named Subjects. Then you could join tables on matching subject_id for example.

It may not be an option though

Comment: @Vinie  above code is working fine but i want do it in other way..i mean any other function because above code is little big..so want to know any other way ..if possible

Comment: @Lunfel the reqirement is if any subject match from the given subjects then it should return true

Comment: Yes, I understand, but still, if changing your DB structure is an option, I would suggest putting subjects in a new table. You could write a query that would replace almost all that code

Comment: @Lunfel ,yeah it is also the right option to put subjects in other table..but then how to match these.?

Comment: Ok, give me a couple of min to make answer. I'll explain how to do it

Answer (score 0):

As I commented out, I would change DB structure to this :

posted_sujects table

```
posted_subjets_id  | degree  | institute_id 
1                     MS        1         
2                    BSC        3
3                    arts       1
```

student table

```
student_id  |  other fields
1              Boby
2              Roger
```

subjects table

```
subject_id | name
1            maths
2            electronics
3            chemistry
```

student_subject table

```
subject_id | student_id
1            1
2            1
1            2
```

post_subject table

```
subject_id | post_id
1            1
2            1
```

Basicaly you can join student_subject with post_subject to match the subjects required and the students. Here is a quick query (not tested out)

```
SELECT * FROM student_subject
INNER JOIN post_subject ON student_subject.subject_id = post_subject.subject_id
```

And then from there you can add GROUP BY clause to group by posts for example.

Comment: i understand what you have explained above..but the main problem for me is comma separated subjects.. explode function